# If and how to properly use a Python-formatted string in Cython

Tags: python, cython

I am wondering how you would declare a variable that takes a Python string like this:

```
current = 'Count: {:,}/{:,} in {:.0f} min | {:,.0f}/min | ETA: {:,.0f} min ({:,.0f} h)'\
                        .format(cnt, total, time_past, count_per_min, eta, eta/60)
```

And would it even make sense to "cythonize" this part?

I assume the reason why

```
cdef char* current
```

won't work is that the length of the string might change and one has to guess.

Comment: Intuitively, I would guess that you won't see any improvement. In the end, you have to create new string objects anyway. But can you not just write a cythonized version of it and compare the timings?

Comment: How would you cythonize it?

Comment: Ah, you mean you want to replace the `format` call and create the string manually and hope for additional speed? I wouldn't try that. After creating the string you probably want to write it somewhere and I am pretty sure that the writing overhead will exceed the string creation overhead.

Comment: Not necessarily, both the binary string formatter and the .format() function raise a `Storing unsafe C derivative of temporary Python reference` here if I try to compile it

Comment: Hmm, I don't have problems compiling that code.

Comment: @SebastianRaschka: You get that error because you are immediately discarding the string.  What you can do is call [`PyMem_Malloc()`](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/memory_allocation.html) and use `memcpy` or a slice expression to copy the string into the allocated buffer.  Don't forget to free it when you're done.  Alternately, take a reference to the Python string and keep it alive.